# Design choice: Any good reason for 'ToArray()' LINQ extension to throw an exception for null collections?

Tags: linq

**Unsurprisingly**, following code will throw an `ArgumentNullException`

```
IEnumerable<string> collection = null;
string[] collectionViewAsAnArray = collection.ToArray();
```

This **looks** obvious at first sight ... but ain't incoherent to argue that returning `null` may have been a reasonnable alternative *(Accounting that `ToArray()` is an extension method and therefor can be called, even on `null`)*.

While I acknowledge, this way, extension behave like a real method, I can't help finding the other approach really smart too ... but this may lead to other issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why push the error to some other spot in your code?  If you expect that something can be null, check it before you use it.  Otherwise throw an error *exactly* at the spot where your assumption was false, namely when you tried to convert it to an array.

I understand it can be debatable when you're chaining operations but in those cases I've found it easier to work with an empty `IEnumerable` rather than a `null` one.

Comment: Thanks @Ron (and @Craig). I like the argument that the _error_ must be raise at exact spot. And don't worry, just indeed came across the situation in a chain of operations and wondered for a while if would have been smart to propagate or not. Depends on the situation of course, but raising at exact spot is a strong enough argument.

Answer (score 3):

Granted `IEnumerable` is an interface used in collections but the underlying implementation is an **object** and you have set that `collection` variable to point to `null`, hence the exception.

If on the other hand you initialized `collection` with:

```
IEnumerable<string> collection = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

OR

```
IEnumerable<string> collection = new List<string>();
```

You would have an empty list **object** that you could act on. The `ArgumentNullException` exception is thrown because the collection **argument** is in fact `null` and that is what `ToArray()` is trying to act on. So logically, to me anyways, this was the only design choice.

**Edit**

On the other hand, in practice, I've made the conscious decision to always return a valid `IEnumerable<T>` when the return type on my class methods are supposed to return an `IEnumerable<T>`.

For example; a method signature that looks like `IEnumerable<T> GetAll()` would always return a valid enumerable and If there was nothing to return then I would return `return Enumerable.Empty<T>();`

The difference here to me is that `GetAll()` is not acting on a collection **argument**. You could really look at this like the collection is really nothing more than a parameter to the method and if you passed in a null parameter to a regular method you would probably throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

---

**The short answer** is that your `collection` variable is an *expected* **argument** (or parameter) to the `ToArray()` method and it is `null` so it makes sense to throw an `ArgumentNullException`.